# Div in section not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, sections

I have problem with `div` in my `section` i want it to follow the picture image (to be in line with it ) like this:
[image]

But instead it just stays on the left side like this:

[image]

I tried changing some styles and div position inside my HTML but nothing seems to work
My code is available at: https://codepen.io/wodosharlatan/pen/jOpLVBQ?editors=1100
Any help is appreciated, but please try to make it as responsive as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your codepen, just change your image width from `256px` to `100%`.

CSS like this:

```css
.portfolio__img {
   width         : 100%   ;   /* change width */
   height        : auto   ;   /* add height auto */
   border-radius : 0.5rem ;
   justify-self  : center ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### TLDR

use `width:max-content` on class `.portfolio__content`

##### Result

[image]

##### Explanation

When you use the CSS property `width: max-content`, you are telling the browser to make the width of an element as small as possible while still being able to fit all the content inside it.

 It will automatically adjust the width of the element to the widest item within it.

this is working fine since you have a specific width for the images, so the width of the card is like this logic `padding size + image width`

##### More details

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content

##### Modified code

```css
/*==================== GOOGLE FONTS ====================*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");

/*==================== VARIABLES CSS ====================*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /* Change favorite color */
  --hue-color: 255;
  /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/
  /* HSL color mode */
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
  --container-color: #fff;
  --scroll-bar-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 90%);
  --scroll-thumb-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 80%);
  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  --body-font: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  /* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: 0.938rem;
  --small-font-size: 0.813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: 0.75rem;
  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  /*========== Margenes Bottom ==========*/
  /* .25rem = 4px, .5rem = 8px, .75rem = 12px ... */
  --mb-0-25: 0.25rem;
  --mb-0-5: 0.5rem;
  --mb-0-75: 0.75rem;
  --mb-1: 1rem;
  --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
  --mb-2: 2rem;
  --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-3: 3rem;
  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-modal: 1000;
}


/* Font size for large devices */

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
   :root {
    --big-font-size: 3rem;
    --h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: 0.875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: 0.813rem;
  }
}


/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/


/*========== Button Dark/Light ==========*/


/*==================== BASE ====================*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*==================== REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ====================*/

.section {
  padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
  color: var(--title-color);
}

.section__subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}


/*==================== LAYOUT ====================*/

.container {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin-left: var(--mb-1-5);
  margin-right: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}


/*==================== BUTTONS ====================*/

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.button__icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: var(--mb-0-5);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button--flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button--small {
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
}

.button--link {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.button--link:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--first-color-alt);
}


/*==================== PORTFOLIO ====================*/

.portfolio__container {
  overflow: initial;
}

.portfolio__content {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  width: max-content;
  /* line of code added from stackoverflow answer */
}

.portfolio__img {
  width: 256px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  justify-self: center;
}

.portfolio__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-5);
}

.portfolio__description {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.portfolio__button:hover .button__icon {
  transform: translate(0.25rem);
}

.swiper-button-prev::after,
.swiper-button-next::after {
  content: "";
}

.swiper-portfolio-icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: -0.5rem;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: -0.5rem;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio section" id="portfolio">
  <h2 class="section__title">Portfolio</h2>
  <span class="section__subtitle">Most recent work</span>

  <div class="portfolio__container container swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!--=================== PORTFOLIO 1 ===================-->
      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQD3U1qBRmQOSJkBX5kmNbdrR_Q7InY1Q4zLEH0fZAjxg&s" alt="" class="portfolio__img" />

        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Error 404</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">Page not found</p>

          <a href="#" class="button button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
                Demo
                <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
              </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```